# Gauss' universal theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I recently came across a set of lecture notes on multivariable calculus. In a section about integral theorems, the standard Gauss' (divergence) theorem was brought up:

$\int_{V}\nabla \cdot \textbf{F} dV = \int_{S} \textbf{F} \cdot d\textbf{S}$.

However, the text also claimed the theorem could be generalized to the statement

$\int_{V} \nabla(x)dV = \int_{S} d\textbf{S}(x)$,

where we for example could have $x=\cdot \textbf{F}$, giving the standard form, or $x=\Phi$ for some scalar field $\Phi$, giving

$\int_{V} \nabla \Phi dV = \int_{S} \Phi d\textbf{S}(x)$.

Unfortunately, no proof was presented. I have struggled to find some more info on the topic, but couldn't find anything.

Any thoughts or comments?

Comment: If $\Phi$ is a scalar field, then your formula is integral by parts, isn't it?

Comment: Just prove it with the usual Gauss's Theorem component by component. I.e., choose an appropriate $\mathbf F$ for each.

Comment: @Lion: I don't think the statement is the integral by parts formula, but I'm sure it could be derived from it.

Comment: @TedShifrin: Sure, I guess that works. However I would have to do that for every different choice of $x$, and I would like a more general proof.